# Change layout of the built-in application

Tags: android, built-in

Is it possible to change the layout of the built-in application of the Android?

I have  Samsung S Duos and I want to change layout of some application(dialer, SMS messenger and phone book(contacts) are not so user-friendly for dual SIM cards)

Is it possible to make buttons of this applications bigger or smaller or to add a new option (sub menu)?

If yes, is there easier way than rewriting and compiling whole Android source? Or maybe there is an option to change the phone book(contacts) and reinstall it as a new application?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: without source code how you will be able to apply changes ? and where you will go on to add the buttons and add a sub menu  - i think it is not possible without source code

Comment: @NetStarter, as I said, maybe there is a source code just of the phone book or dialer, that I can change and reinstall it as a new application

Comment: ok if you have the source code go ahead make the changes and reinstall it but if you don't have any source code then you can not change any application- but you must be sure while doing any changes

Comment: @NetStarter, that's the question! I'm wondering if there are any source code for this. Basically your comments are just what I asked in the question, so I don't see how are you helping in any way

Comment: Lol what netstart is saying is that unless you built the application or know who built it you most likely won't be able to do it legally.  You would have to know how to code and would have to have access full access to your phone and most likely the source code is not available. So now do you see how he's helping you?

Comment: @RichTalcik, still no. I have sufficient experience with building applications for Android. I believe that if _full access_ to my phone will be required, rooting it won't be a problem. And if your help is only `most likely the source code is not available` then I don't see how this can be helpful. If you don't know, why bother commenting? I searched for the source code with no result, so I also think that source code may not be available. But maybe someone knows or has it or I can somehow extract it from the Android source... That what I'm hopping to get in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make buttons of this applications bigger or smaller or to add a new option (sub menu)?

Somebody with sufficient experience could do this, yes.

> is there easier way than rewriting and compiling whole Android source?

No. And even that is insufficient, as the result will not run on your phone without the requisite drivers.

Instead, find a ROM mod that can run on your phone, then start with that ROM mod's source and make your changes.

> Or maybe there is an option to change the phone book(contacts) and reinstall it as a new application?

It is conceivable, though unlikely, that the maintainers of your chosen ROM mod have arranged for some of these apps to be buildable as SDK apps. Most likely, this is not an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't just edit the application without having the source and recompiling it. You can modify your build.prop to edit your screen density value. If you change this, you will have more (Or less) buttons etc. on your screen. But editing this file is very dangerous and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first off your the one that needs help so you dont have to be rude, secondly the source code is not going to be in your phone because its going to be a binary file. And unless you know how to convert a binary conputer kanguage fike to source code then your sol.  This website is not a place where we write code for you. If you have no code to display then theres not much we can help with. And the only people that have the actual source code are going to be the developers that made the application which are the developers that made your phone.  In this case shoot an email to your phones company which is samsung and see if they will release you an open source code that you can go off of. That should answer your question on how to get the source code. If they dont give it to you then you cant get it.